# Thread get - just metadata

Tags: gmail-api

I am doing full sync this way: list of `/threads` and then a request to get each of the thread like `/threads/{id}`. However this returns me every message together with it's body data -> and I just want to fetch the metadata of the messages. I can see that in get '`messages/{id}`' you can specify format but not in get `threads/{id}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by metadata you mean the headers (no body). You can use the `fields` parameter to get just that (*messages/payload/headers*):

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/{thread-id}?fields=messages%2Fpayload%2Fheaders&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Answer (score 2):

Threads.get() now supports format=METADATA and with that you can use the new "metadataIncludeHeaders" to further limit the headers list to a select few.  This is much more efficient than using "fields" as it only fetches what is necessary from the backend rather than filtering it later on:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get